# How to make Database to support Multiple Languages

Tags: oracle

How to make the database to support national language characters if there are any special characters in languages other than English it is showing as ?.

For example :`AQUAFRESH Мой первый зубик` is showing as `AQUAFRESH ??? ?????? ?????` in Database.

Database is not supporting Language other than English.

The data is showing correct in the application (front end) but incorrect in database.  Can you please suggest what database settings needs to be changed to get the correct characters in the database.

Comment: are you using Oracle or MySQL?

Comment: Using Oracle (TOAD)

Comment: Which version of toad are you using?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "data is showing correct in the application (front end) but incorrect in database"? The database doesn't show anything, it stores the data and hands it back to you (your app) when commanded. If you used the right types, you're good to go as far as the data's integrity is concerned. The database's language doesn't affect storage but it will affect display and some tasks (e.g. sort).

Applications need to be able to handle the types, languages and fonts. For instance, if you use a version of TOAD that does that not support Cyrillic characters, it won't render the data correctly even though it is stored correctly in your database. That's why you see the ???????? when you retrieve non-ANSI character data.

Older version of TOAD did not support all Unicode characters and fonts by default (they did EASCII/ANSI); you needed a Unicode version of TOAD that had the right font support and/or the right NLS_LANG setting. Check your version of TOAD against their specs to see if you have both the language support and font support.

It used to be a really weird dance getting the settings right between the OS, Oracle, TOAD, SQL*PLUS and whatever else you have running. That's largely gone with recent versions of the product stack. I think TOAD's been Unicode enabled since Toad 10 but please verify. If you are not or cannot get on the latest version, check out TOAD's documentation or the Oracle community in Toadworld for workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Oracle in a long time, but I assume you are using `CHAR` datatypes (`CHAR`, `VARCHAR2`, `CLOB`, and `LONG`) instead of `NCHAR` datatypes (`NCHAR`, `NCLOB`, and `NVARCHAR2`)? You should have a couple of different options:

1. Change the column(s) to use a particular 8-bit encoding / locale (this might require changing the database itself)
2. Change the column(s) to use a Unicode encoding
3. Convert the column(s) to one of the `NCHAR` datatypes (i.e. Unicode-only `NCHAR`, `NCLOB`, and `NVARCHAR2`).

   Please note, as per @WernfriedDomscheit in a comment on this Answer:

   > Nowadays the default character set for Oracle Database is AL32UTF8...`NCHAR` / `NVARCHAR` are not required anymore...They mainly persist for legacy reasons.

Please see the following documentation:

1. [Overview of Globalization Support](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch1overview.htm)
2. [Choosing a Character Set](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch2charset.htm)
3. [Locale Data](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/applocaledata.htm)
4. [Character Set Migration](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch11charsetmig.htm)

Comment: `NCHAR` is a bad suggestions due to the padding that is applied to those columns. `NVARCHAR` would be a **much** better choice

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I completely agree and did not actually recommend a specific type, but rather one of the 3 `NCHAR` types that were listed in the top paragraph. However, I can see that how I worded it was a bit unclear so I have updated it to be clearer.

Comment: Nowadays the default character set for Oracle Database is `AL32UTF8`, i.e. even `CHAR`, `VARCHAR2` or `CLOB` supports any Unicode character. `NCHAR/NVARCHAR` are not required anymore in these days. They mainly persist for legacy reason.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thanks for that info. I have added it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your font is not able to display such characters. Check you settings in TOAD and select a font which support Unicode. You can use this page to verify which font supports Unicode: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/fontlist.htm